# Multiple Azure AD Authentication Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I would like to know if it's possible to setup a .NET Core Application using IdentityServer 4 that can Authenticate to more than one AzureAd configuration.

Currently you can add 1 AzureAD configuration like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

But I wanted to be able to Authenticate users from multiple Organisations using AzureAd. So different TenantId...etc

This will have to be done on the fly depending on the organisation chosen in the UI.

How can I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `AddOpenIdConnect` middleware :

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddOpenIdConnect("AADTenant1", "AADTenant1", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "<app1>";
    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant1>/";             
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc-aadtenant1";            
    options.SaveTokens = true;                                 
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddOpenIdConnect("AADTenant2", "AADTenant2", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "<app2>";
    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant2>/";             
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc-aadtenant2";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

})
```

And trigger the scheme you want to challenge :

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback");

var props = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = callbackUrl,
    Items =
    {
        { "scheme", provider },
        { "returnUrl", returnUrl }
    }
};

return Challenge(provider, props);
```